# ¿Duda sobre eventos con JS en una clase?

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom, navegador-web

qué tal?

Estoy creando un juego de memoria de encontrar la otra imagen igual, para esto estoy usando una clase o prototipo.

Para mostrar la imagen uso el evento `onclick`

```
piezaUno.addEventListener('click', this.animationUno);

animationUno(event) {
              imgPiezaUno.style.opacity = '1';

           }
```

y así muestra la imagen. En el momento tengo 10 piezas para comparar o sea ese mismo codigo 10 veces con su pieza, evento y función aparte.

Mi problema radica en que no he podido encontrar la forma de validar si una pieza seleccionada es la misma o no que la otra pieza seleccionada, intente escuchar el mismo evento en todas las piezas pero con la misma función así:

```
piezaUno.addEventListener('click', this.findPairs);

findPairs(event) {


                var src = event.target.firstElementChild.src;
                var comprobar = [];
                comprobar.push(src);

                console.log(comprobar);
                console.log(event);

            }
```

Todas las piezas tiene esa misma función y mi idea era que cada vez que se ejecutara el evento con una pieza se guardara el src en en el array y cuando ejecutara con otra quedaran en el mismo array y poder hacer la comparación con los src ya encapsulados, pero esa función se ejecuta diferente para cada pieza, o sea si se guarda el src pero no se acomula, cada src se guarda en un array diferente.

(Todas las piezas tienen dos `addEventListener` así:

```
                piezaUno.addEventListener('click', this.animationUno);
                piezaUno.addEventListener('click', this.findPairs);

                piezaDos.addEventListener('click', this.animationDos);
                piezaDos.addEventListener('click', this.findPairs);
```

)

¡Trate de crear lo mejor que pude la pregunta, no me crucifiquen y muchas gracias al que me pueda ayudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría algo así:

```js
var imagenSeleccionada;

function manejarEvento(target){
 
  if(imagenSeleccionada){
    
    if(target.src == imagenSeleccionada.src){
    
      alert("son iguales");
      
    }
    else {  imagenSeleccionada = null;  }
  }
  else { 
   imagenSeleccionada = target;
  }

}
```

```html
<img src="https://mobile-cdn.123rf.com/300wm/pingebat/pingebat1507/pingebat150700039/42558784-alto-detalle-vector-de-la-bola-de-f%C3%BAtbol-.jpg?ver=6"
style="width: 100px" onclick="manejarEvento(this)"
/>

<img src="https://mobile-cdn.123rf.com/300wm/pingebat/pingebat1507/pingebat150700039/42558784-alto-detalle-vector-de-la-bola-de-f%C3%BAtbol-.jpg?ver=6"
style="width: 100px;" onclick="manejarEvento(this)"
/>
```

Una sola función para manejar el evento del click `manejarEvento(target)` que recibe como parámetro el elemento al que se le hizo click (target).

Una variable llamada `imagenSeleccionada` que sirve para guardar el elemento al que se le ha hecho click para después compararlo con el siguiente elemento.

Cuando se hace click, se llama la función `manejarEvento()`. Dentro de esa función se evalúa si `imagenSeleccionada` tiene valor, eso quiere decir que ya se ha seleccionado una imagen antes. Si `imagenSeleccinada` tiene valor entonces se evalua si la propiedad `src` de la imagen guardada es igual al `src` del target, si son iguales entonces se ejecuta el código correspondiente, en este caso un `alert()`. Si no son iguales entonces `imagenSeleccionada` vuelve a ser `null`.

Si es la primera vez que se presiona una imagen entonces `imagenSeleccionada` será igual al `target`.